# Disabling IPv4 through CMD/Registry

Tags: java, windows, registry, cmd, ipv4

Im working on a program in Java (for Windows only), that creates PPPoE connection (its not really that important). Important is, that I need to *SOMEHOW* disable IPv4 in a Local Area Network tab.

[problem http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/3253/4dcb10eb731a403e9fc785e.png](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/3253/4dcb10eb731a403e9fc785e.png)

(its in Czech language)

I need to somehow "uncheck" the IPv4 protocol in a ceratin network adapter. Im able to set a number of stuff through CMD and *netsh* tool, but I wasnt able to manage to disable IPv4 protocol *for a single adapter*. I know how to disable IPv4 for the whole computer, but this doesnt work for me (since I need IPv4 communication, just through different channel).
I know how to "uncheck" the IPv6 through Windows Registry (I found it on the internet) but the same doesnt work for IPv4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The result I need to achieve (programatically)

[result http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8459/bfebacf3b9bb428c84dee44.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8459/bfebacf3b9bb428c84dee44.png)

PS: Please dont ask why I make Windows-only app in Java...

Comment: I know how to do this in C++, would that be satisfactory?  I doubt there's any way to do it in Java alone, but you could have a small C++ program just for this task that your Java program can call.

Comment: Well, I might figure out a way to execute it. Can I pass the adapter I want to disable IPv4 at to that program of Yours?
Id be really glad for Your help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

See Microsoft sample code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/17/how-to-enable-disable-ipv6-programmatically-in-windows-vista.aspx).

You'll want to replace the reference to ms_tcpip6 with ms_tcpip, and you may need to experiment a bit to work out how to identify the right adapter.  This additional code fragment may help, it belongs in the inner loop:

```
        [...]
        while (hr == S_OK) 
        {
            LPWSTR lpszPathToken;
            hr = pncbp->GetPathToken(&lpszPathToken);
            if (hr != S_OK) fail(hr);
            wprintf(L"Path token: %s\n", lpszPathToken);

            // Get owner

            INetCfgComponent *owner;
            LPWSTR lpszOwner;

            hr = pncbp->GetOwner(&owner);
            if (hr != S_OK) fail(hr);

            hr = owner->GetId(&lpszOwner);
            if (hr != S_OK) fail(hr);

            wprintf(L"Path owner: %s\n", lpszOwner);
            // Disable this binding.

            hr = pncbp->Enable(ENABLE);
            [...]
```

Hopefully either the path token or the path owner will give you the information you need to identify the right adapter.

Comment: I might test it, but I dont know if this program would run on a standard PC without any frameworks etc (since it requires some windows kit to build). But if nothing will work Ill have to try this.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need any additional libraries installed, DDK only exposes windows internals.

Comment: You need the DDK to compile this code, but not to run it.  I've used it myself on machines without the DDK installed.  If you set Visual C++ to use the static runtime library, you won't need to distribute that either.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tool : https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850

```
nvspbind is a tool for modifying network bindings from the command line. It is especially useful in Server Core environments with the Hyper-V role enabled.

It can be used to set the correct bindings for NICs used in Virtual Networks.

It can also be used to enable or disable specific bindings on any NIC and to query and change the NIC connection order.

It utilizes the INetCfg APIs documented on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms805265.aspx).

Most options are documented in the readme and nvpsbind.txt which download with the install.

To get help run “nvspbind.exe /?”
```